# Replacing NA values to 0

Tags: r, replace, na

Sorry this is my first time posting but I had a question regarding replacement of NA values for my assignment. The assignment states that I have to replace all values that has `"A"` with `0`.
So I tried this command :

```
test1[test1 == "A"] <- 0
```

But all it did was generate `NA` values. I tried turning these `NA` values to a 0 with another command

```
test1[is.na(test1)] <- 0
```

But I get `"invalid factor level, NA generated"` warnings. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your variable is of class `factor` (run `class(test1)` to validate) and `0` is not one of the levels. The warning message says it pretty clearly Why would you want to replace `A` with a zero anyway? Either way, if you want to add random classes to your vector, it is better to work with a `character` vector instead.

Comment: Doing `class(test1)` and it returned me with `data.frame`. I'm trying to replace A with a zero because that's what my assignment asked me to do.

Comment: If `test1` is `data.frame` are you trying to replace `A`s in all the columns to zeros? Also, how did you read the data? Maybe specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while reading in order to avoid to factor conversion in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to replace every single `A` with a 0. The command I used to read the data was `read.table(file=file.choose())`. Nvm about the error with `stringAsFactors` I just had to change the system local of my system.

Comment: No, `stringsAsFactors` is a param for `read.table`

Comment: So if your file has header and it is comma-separated, then you'd run `read.table(file = file.choose(), sep=",", header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: AHHH it finally works. Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
test1 <- c("A","B","C","A","C")
test1 <- replace(test1, test1=="A", 0)
test1
```

prints

```
> test1
[1] "0" "B" "C" "0" "C"
```

for data frame:

```
> test2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("A","B","A"),
+                     col2 = c("D","B","A"),
+                     col3 = c("A","A","X"))
> apply(test2, 1, function(x) {replace(x, x=="A", 0)})
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
col1 "0"  "B"  "0" 
col2 "D"  "B"  "0" 
col3 "0"  "0"  "X"
```

and to convert it back to data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(apply(test2, 1, function(x) {replace(x, x=="A", 0)}))
```

Comment: I've tried that command before and it didn't work for my data. Maybe it's because i have 316 rows and 2266 columns that I have to use a different command? I tried researching my problems but got no results.

Comment: What's your data? `matrix`,`data.frame` ?

Comment: You haven't updated to a `data.frame` because `apply` converted it back to a `matrix` which in turn converted all the factors to characters. OP just has a factor column. The warning message is pretty clear about that.